# Exponential of operator and applying it a arbitrary state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space

> Let $K$ be any Matrix, not necessarily the hamitonian. Is $e^{-Kt}\left|\psi\right>$ equal to $e^{-K\left|\psi\right>t}$ even if it is not the the eigenvector of $K$?

I think so as i just taylor expand the $e^{-Kt}$ out but I want to confirm.

In that case can i say that $\left<\psi\right|e^{-Kt}\left|\psi\right>$ = $e^{-\left<\psi\right|K\left|\psi\right>t}$?

Comment: What is $e^{-Kt\left|\psi\right>}$?

Comment: @Valter Moretti another matrix exponential and can again be taylor expanded.

Comment: $Kt|\psi\rangle$ is not a matrix, is a vector!

Comment: @Valter Moretti yes (n by 1), thanks. But is $\left<\psi\right|e^{-Kt}\left|\psi\right>$ = $e^{-\left<\psi\right|K\left|\psi\right>t}$ true? I taylor expand $e^{-Kt}$ and then recombine the result into a exponential of a scalar?

Comment: Yes a vector $v$ is a matrix $1\times n$, but it does not matter here:  what is   $v^n$?

Comment: No it is not true, even in the last form you wrote in the comment. It is well known that even for self-adjoint operators $\langle\psi, A\psi\rangle^2\neq \langle \psi, A^2\psi\rangle$, and obviously it also differs for higher powers.

Comment: yuggib answered before I could.  ($\psi$ is supposed not to be an eigenvector of $A$)

Comment: @Valter Moretti  thanks. what is the condition for the last equation to be true, other than being the eigenstate of K?

Comment: @yuggib thanks. I understand now. Is being the eigenstate of K the only condition for it to be true?

Comment: @yuggib $A^2 \propto A$ also leads to this. I wonder if there is more.

Comment: The condition, if $K$ is self adjoint is just that $K\psi=\lambda \psi$, so $\psi$ is an eigenstate of $K$ necessarily

Comment: @peterphys You need to take more care. $A^2 \propto A$ does *not* imply that $\langle e^{A}\rangle = e^{\langle A \rangle}$.

Answer (score 2):

I consider only your last identity for the matrix  $K$ supposed to be Hermitian. Suppose that $$\langle \psi| e^{tK}\psi \rangle = e^{t \langle \psi|K\psi \rangle}\tag{1}$$ for every $t \in \mathbb R$ and some vector $\psi$. Taking the second derivative at $t=0$ of both sides you have
$$\langle \psi|K^2\psi \rangle = \langle \psi | K\psi \rangle^2$$ 
that is, since $K^*=K$,
$$\langle K\psi|K\psi \rangle = \langle \psi | K\psi \rangle^2\:,$$
which can be rewritten as 
$$||K\psi||^2 = \langle \psi | K\psi \rangle^2\:.\tag{2}$$
Since $\psi\neq 0$, otherwise (1) is trivially false, we can assume $||\psi||=1$ by dividing both sides of (2) by the actual norm of $\psi$.
Cauchy-Schwartz inequality yields ($ \langle \psi | K\psi \rangle$ is real as $K=K^*$)
 $$||K\psi||^2 =\langle \psi | K\psi \rangle^2 
= |\langle \psi | K\psi \rangle|^2   \leq ||K\psi||^2 ||\psi||^2 = ||K\psi||^2 $$
and thus (use again $||\psi||=1$)
$$|\langle \psi | K\psi \rangle| = ||K\psi||\: ||\psi||$$
The inequality by Cauchy and Schwartz is saturated if and only if the two involved vectors are linearly dependent, i.e.,
$$K\psi = \lambda \psi\:.$$ 
We have found that if (1) holds then $\psi$ is an eigenvector of $K$.